# Symfony3 auto generate specific value

Tags: php, annotations, symfony-3.1

I have an entity named User and i have a property $money. When someone registers I want to register him with money always starting from 5000. I am using Symfony3 and i want to do it using annotations.
  For example I have this property

```
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
```

I am trying to use the same type of annotations but to generate always the same value. Here are my annotations so far for $money

```
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="money", type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 */
private $money;
```

My problem is that i dont know what to put between the brackets and even if this is the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to say but I don't think there is a way to do that with annontations. What you could do is:

```
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="money", type="integer")
 */
private $money = 5000;
```

This way a new user will always have 5000 when created.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way :

```
public function __construct()
    {
       $this->money= 5000;
    }
```